# XAMPP apache will not start

Tags: apache, xampp

I had to reinstall my max with El capitan, and I had XAMPP working with mysql and apache able to start servers. Now my apache server isn't able to start so I can't get to phpmyadmin to do some schoolwork.

I've looked around and saw that it could be a port 80 or 81 issue, so I checked and saw that no applications were currently using the port, either way I still got a no go.

I tried through terminal to see an error message,

```
Starting XAMPP for Mac OS X 5.6.30-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Starting diagnose... 
XAMPP:  Sorry, I've no idea what's going wrong. 
XAMPP:  Please contact our forum http://www.apachefriends.org/f/ 
Last 10 lines of "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error_log":
tail: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/error.log: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
Contents of "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/proftpd/start.err":
C02L58UUFFT1.corp.proofpoint.com proftpd[1780]: warning: unable to determine IP address of 'C02L58UUFFT1.corp.proofpoint.com'
C02L58UUFFT1.corp.proofpoint.com proftpd[1780]: error: no valid servers configured
C02L58UUFFT1.corp.proofpoint.com proftpd[1780]: Fatal: error processing configuration file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf'
C02L58UUFFT1:~ sblomquist$ lsof -i ':80'
C02L58UUFFT1:~ sblomquist$ lsof -i ':81'
```

Thought I would post my problem here while I browse around for more possible solutions.

Comment: This sounds more like a server configuration issue than a coding issue. I'd try serverfault.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll remove this and try there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update your system and install net-tools

On ubuntu, `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install net-tools -y` restart your server